# XML Serialization within encrypted assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xml

It seems I am unable to properly serialize / save a class in C# due to the fact that the assembly is encrypted. I also obfuscate the assembly, however the class being serialized is not obfuscated, so that's not the issue.

I was under the impression that .NET used Reflection (which works completely fine) for XML, not the metadata, so why is it trying to read the metadata?

The error:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Downloads\beta3\beta_starter.exe' could not be opened -- 'An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. '
at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
at Plugins.Xml.Save[T](T data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a related topic, which also uses themida. It seems you have to use System.Runtime.Serialization.

Reference: [Deserialization fail when using themida protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651840/deserialization-fail-when-using-themida-protection)