# OAuthRequestValidator TypeLoadException in Medium Trust

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am working with Intuit.Ipp to access QuickBooks Desktop data. I have been working fine locally, however, after deploying my code to our server I started receiving a TypeLoadException when trying to instantiate the OAuthRequestValidator. I believe this might be related to the fact that our server is configured to use MediumTrust which is not allowing the Serialization to happen. Is OAuthRequestValidator known to not support MediumTrust? Is there anything I can do to get it to work?

Here is the exception:

```
    System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 
        'Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. 
        Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.   
        at Intuit.Ipp.Security.OAuthRequestValidator..ctor(String accessToken, String accessTokenSecret, String consumerKey, String consumerSecret)
```

Comment: Are your dlls on a shared directory by any chance?

Comment: Are any of the SDK binaries NOT in your app's /bin directory?  I think the medium trust setting prevents you from seeing anything outside that.

Comment: I don't know if it is on a shared directory since I don't have access to the server itself, we're using Rackspace Cloud Sites to host it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion it has to do with the fact that the XML Serializer requires a temporary directory for it's temporary files, and you can't access it.  There's a way to set that directory explicitly, I wonder if you can tinker with that and find one that works.  See [Safest place for the XmlSerializer to save temp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660439/safest-place-for-the-xmlserializer-to-save-temp-files?rq=1)

Comment: I tried setting the xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation but it didn't seem to have any effect. I believe all my SDK binaries are in the /bin folder since it works locally and none are in the GAC.